# Updating value in tables selected from sys.columns and sys.tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of our user's IDs has been updated in one table, but not in the other 63 tables within the database. I need to update this ID in all the other tables with the UserID column.

I've managed to select all the tables I need from sys.tables and sys.columns, I am just not 100% sure how to update the value in each of these tables.

I'm selecting the tables using this query:

```sql
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%UserID%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

This gives me a list of all the relevant tables and column names.

I modified the above query to generate SQL too:

```sql
declare @newID varchar(12) = '149080'
declare @oldID varchar(12) = '146423'

SELECT 'UPDATE ' + t.name + ' SET ' + c.name + ' = ' + @newID + ' WHERE ' + c.name + ' = ' + @oldID + ';'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name = 'UserID'
```

Is there a way to execute these statements?

Comment: You'll need to use `sp_executesql` and pass `@newID` and `@oldID` as parameters (not inject them). But if this *has* happened this sounds like you don't have your foreign keys constraints set up correctly; which means you should be looking at those too, as then this kind of thing can't happen.

Comment: You can wrap a cursor around it and use `EXECUTE`. But as @Larnu mentioned you should rather alter your schema and use foreign key constraints with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Or even better don't use the name as primary key but a surrogate ID, e.g. some number, that doesn't need to be updated when the name changes.

Comment: Thanks guys - this ID isn't a "proper" ID (PK), but is actually linked to another DB on another server (arrgh!!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you'll need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this. One way would be the below:

```
DECLARE @newID int = 149080; --Changed datatype, I assume correct
DECLARE @oldID int = 146423; datatype, I assume correct

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N' SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N'= @NewID WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = @OldID;'
                  FROM sys.columns c
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                       JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                  WHERE c.[name] = N'UserID'
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend for debugging
--SELECT @SQL; --If @SQL has a value more than 4,000 characters
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@NewID int, @OldID int', @NewID = @newID, @OldId = @oldID;
```

`PRINT` and `SELECT` will help you debug. But, also like I said in the comments, you probably want to look at your foreign key constraints here.

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer, `QUOTENAME` and all ;-)

Comment: @DanGuzman As was I. Only thing I would add though is that it is probably wise to include the schema name in the update too. Although the OP has done so, it is probably not ideal to assume everything resides in a single schema.

Comment: I agree as well @GarethD . The OP hadn't in their answer, but that doesn't excuse my "laziness".

Comment: You're welcome @Luke (just noticed a typo, which i assume you fixed, which hopefully means you understand it too). If not, please do ask.